# Force form field value on page load & submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I force a specific value within a form field on page load; and have that value 'Submit'  with JavaScript or jQuery?

I tried the below; but no cigar.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.forms['coolform'].submit()

}
</script>
```

Mark-Up.

```
    <form id="search" name="coolform" class="navbar-form form-search" action="#">                    
        <div class="input-append">
            <input id="query" type="text" class="search-query" value="Bars" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>

        </div>
```

Comment: afaik you cannot submit just one of the values within the form. You can though use ajax and send request (imitate the form sending a value) to some external page which will deal with your request. Your page will not reload this way too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
     var s = $('#search');
     $('#query', s).val('The value you want to force in.');      
     s.submit();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="query" name="query" type="text" class="search-query" value="Bars" >
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use ajax to submit the value on document.ready...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var query = $('#query').value;
    $.ajax({
       url:'url/to/your.php',
       data:'query='+query,
       success:function(data){
          //handle response
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a `name` attribute on the form field, otherwise it won't be included when the form is submitted:

```
<input id="query" name="query" type="text" class="search-query" value="Bars" >
```

Comment: Tried moving within <input> tag as mentioned no cigar.

Comment: @1977: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @1977: An actual "nothing" very rarely happens. Is the form submitted? What's included if it's submitted? Do you get any Javascript errors? If the form is not automatically submitted, can you submit it manually?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.